# Merge or keep two electricity meters for one property?

Tags: electrical, united-kingdom

I’m merging my two adjacent properties therefore decided to merge the electricity supply coming into the property and only have one bill (currently different suppliers). My electrician has linked all the power cables etc into my main property’s fuse board  and says it’s a simple job for UK PowerNetwork to disconnect the loop that went into my annex, which will mean I don’t have to pay the standing daily charge for that meter.

Here’s the issue… the quote from UKPower for doing this is nearly £700! Should have done cost investigations before the job but it all sounded so simple. On top of these costs my supplier has to come and remove the meter in the Annexe (another cost of course).

Can I keep two meters for one property and continue to pay the standing charge in the annexe (my calculations suggest it would take 5 years to break even!)?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're looking for here.  It sounds like you have already committed to getting from two meters to one meter and you just want to rant about the costs.

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based and cost-related. We don't do either here. Please see the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: You have two meter points so you'll get two bills.  This may cause some confusion at one address (when somebody tries to switch supplier they might switch the 'wrong' MPAN), but I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong.  You'll pay two standing charges (~£180pa at the moment) but you seem fine with that. However there's also a 'logical disconnection' procedure by which your billing company (not UKPN) either removes the meter or disables it - ask them about costs for that. That keeps the wires live but stops the standing charge. https://www.ukpowernetworks.co.uk/electricity/disconnect

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the rant, the question seems to be:

> "Can I just keep paying for a meter I am not using?"

The answer would be yes. Presumably you'll want (or already have) the power connected to the supplier with the lower cost per kWh.

I don't know how this works in the UK, but in the US, a service disconnect and meter removal can often be imposed at no additional cost to you for non-payment of bills, so you might want to investigate (**not** *experiment with*, in case it works very differently there) what would happen if you just stopped paying the supplier of that meter.

Comment: If you stop paying bills you get sued, and then eventually disconnected, and then you get sued for the cost of disconnection. This would not be a wise course of action. It is possible a prepayment meter will be fitted but you are still obliged to pay the daily standing charge, even if the meter cuts you off for having no credit.